# Unable to do DOM manipulations with React and material table

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make sure that a password field is instantly replaced with asterisks as the user types it in, but I can't seem to get it to work. Is it because the edit field has its own separate state? Because running the following in the console works:

```
const value = document.getElementById('name-field').value;
const replacedValue = value.replace(/./g, "*");
document.getElementById('name-field').value = replacedValue;
```

But running it as in the below code, it doesn't apply the change: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-gbp27u?file=CustomTableEditField.js)

Comment: Direct DOM manipulations are a react anti-pattern.

Comment: I understand and I've used the password type, but I need specifically asterisks, while maintaining the Edit component's state, as I cannot create a new form property with material table on save (ie, there is one prop per field, which is why onChange, I wanted to replace with `'*'`

Comment: Why don't you set the input's type to `password` ? Wouldn't that have the same effect ?

Comment: `•` isn't the same as `*`

Comment: Well, you can use the browser's default mask with a "password" field, or roll your own maskable regular text input. Is this a design spec taken too literally?